# In TornadoFX, how can I bind BigDecimal properites to another BigDecimal property using objectBinding?

Tags: java, javafx, properties, kotlin, tornadofx

I'm trying to create a binded `BigDecimal` property that is a calculation of two other `BigDecimal` properites, like this:

```
val caculatedProperty: ObjectProperty<BigDecimal> = objectBinding<Any, BigDecimal>(sumProperty, discountProperty) { ... }
```

...like I would do with `StringProperty` or `IntegerProperty`, and it would otherwise work without issues. However, this time I get a type mismatch: it expects `ObjectProperty<BigDecimal>`, but receives `ObjectBinding<BigDecimal?>`.

What's the problem here? Did I use the `objectProperty()` method incorrectly? Should I use some other method to create a binding of a custom object?

EDIT:

The issue was that I was trying to override the `ObjectProperty<BigDecimal>` from parent class with `ObjectBinding<BigDecimal>`. The solution, in my case, was to make the original `ObjectProperty<BigDecimal>` abstract, and leave implementation to the classes that inherit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the `xBinding` functions returns bindings, not properties. If you think about it, how would a calculated property behave if it was writable? Should it write back into the underlying properties perhaps? TornadoFX actually supports these kinds of proxy properties as well, but I suspect that's not what you're after.

Are you wondering why you get `ObjectBinding<BigDecimal?>` instead of `ObjectBinding<BigDecimal>`?

The reason is that the underlying property might be null, and if so we might want to return null from the calculated binding as well.

This normally doesn't create an issue, the property is still observable and would carry the correct calculated `BigDecimal` value.

Comment: Is there a way to create a (perhaps read-only) `Property` from a `Binding`? I want to use my bindings in the ItemViewModel, but I cannot use `bind {}` because it is a `Binding`, not a `Property`...

Comment: I've used `ReadOnlyObjectWrapper` to turn a Binding into a `ReadOnlyObjectProperty`. Is there a better way?

Comment: Interesting issue indeed. I'll look into this during the weekend and get back to you :)